# RAID5 array over-provisioning by creating smaller array?

Tags: raid, ssd

I did actually read the following thread: [How to over-provision an Intel SSD RAID Array via the Dell H700 PERC RAID Controller](https://serverfault.com/questions/276084/how-to-over-provision-an-intel-ssd-raid-array-via-the-dell-h700-perc-raid-contro)

It did give much information, however not an answer to my question in specific.

For example; I have 6x 250 GB SSD's in RAID 6 this will give me about 931 GB total space for the array.

Let's say I only assign 500 GB from it to my array, wouldn't the rest be used for over-provisioning? Or should I still use the hdparm command?

I also searched for this on Google, but also no answer on this. Just want to get it correct before I do some stupid. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The true, bullet-proof way to overprovision SSDs is using the appropriate SATA commands, via (for example) `hdparm`

That said, basically all recent SSD controllers can automatically understand when less space is used (for example, due to small partitions) and use that free space as dynamic overprosion.

Due to how the remapping table works, this can be done basically "for free" (the SSD anyway need to track the used/not used LBA and their mapping with actual NAND blocks).